# What are R's equivalents to Perl's map and grep?

Tags: r, perl, dictionary, functional-programming

I am interested in (functional) vector manipulation in `R`. Specifically, what are `R`'s equivalents to Perl's [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) and [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html)?

The following Perl script greps the even array elements and multiplies them by 2:

```
@a1=(1..8); 
@a2 = map {$_ * 2} grep {$_ % 2 == 0} @a1;
print join(" ", @a2)
# 4 8 12 16
```

How can I do that in `R`? I got this far, using `sapply` for Perl's `map`:

```
> a1 <- c(1:8)
> sapply(a1, function(x){x * 2})
[1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16
```

Where can I read more about such functional array manipulations in `R`?

Also, is there a `Perl` to `R` phrase book, similar to the [Perl Python Phrasebook](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PerlPhrasebook)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

R has "grep", but it works entirely different than what you're used to. R has something much better built in: it has the ability to create array slices with a boolean expression:

```
a1 <- c(1:8)
a2 <- a1 [a1 %% 2 == 0]
a2
[1] 2 4 6 8
```

For map, you can apply a function as you did above, but it's much simpler to just write:

```
a2 * 2
[1]  4  8 12 16
```

Or in one step:

```
a1[a1 %% 2 == 0] * 2
[1]  4  8 12 16
```

I have never heard of a Perl to R phrase book, if you ever find one let me know! In general, R has less documentation than either perl or python, because it's such a niche language.

Answer (score 10):

Quick ones:

- Besides `sapply`, there are also `lapply()`, `tapply`, `by`, `aggregate` and more in the base.  Then there are loads of add-on package on [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org) such as [plyr](http://cran.r-project.org/package=plyr).
- For basic functional programming as in other languages:  `Reduce()`, `Map()`, `Filter()`, ... all of which are on the same help page; try `help(Reduce)` to get started.
- As noted in the earlier answer, vectorisation is even more appropriate here.
- As for `grep`, R actually has three regexp engines built-in, including a Perl-based version from libpcre.
- You seem to be missing a few things from R that are there. I'd suggest a good recent book on R and the S language; my recommendation would be Chambers (2008) ["Software for Data Analysis"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387759352)